# Access ListBoxItem children

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a ListBox which gets populated dynamically by my own class. This is an example of my listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mylistbox" SelectionChanged="timelinelistbox_SelectionChanged_1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding userid}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding postid}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <Image Source="{Binding thumbnailurl}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}" />
                <Image Source="{Binding avatar}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When the SelectedItemChanged event of the ListBox gets triggered I get my ListBoxItem.
But now I want to alter the children in that ListBoxItem... But I can't seem to access the children of the ListBoxItem?

I tried:

```
private void timelinelistbox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the data object that represents the current selected item
    MyOwnClass data = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as MyOwnClass;

    //Get the selected ListBoxItem container instance    
    ListBoxItem selectedItem = this.timelinelistbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data) as ListBoxItem;

    // change username and display
    data.username = "ChangedUsername";
    selectedItem.Content = data;
}
```

But the username doesn't change...

Comment: Can you also add how your `MyOwnClass` class looks like in regards to `username` property?

Comment: did you call the DataBind() after the change in the username.

Comment: You mean "selectedItem.DataContext = data;" ? That still doesn't work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change back `Content` of selected `ListBoxItem`. `MyOwnClass` is a class, I assume, and therefore reference type so changing `username` in one instance will have effect in all references to the same object. Your `MyOwnClass` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) and raise `PropertyChanged` event each time property changes. Like that you notify all bound controls that the property has changed and need refreshing:

```
public class MyOwnClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _username;

    public string username 
    {
        get { return _username ; }
        set
        {
            if (_userName == value) return;
            _userName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("username");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  
}
```

and then it will be enough if you do:

```
private void timelinelistbox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as MyOwnClass).username = "ChangedUsername";
}
```